# Activating :hover effect on picture gallery on pageload

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, css-animations, mousehover

I have a section on my website that has pictures of headshots. When you hover them, the picture changes. It's a pretty cool effect, but because the section is on the bottom of the page...people might not notice that you can hover you mouse on the images to see the effect.

Thus, I was wondering...is there a way through javascript to apply the hover effect to each image, one-by-one, so they change without having to do the mouseover event? Then, when you do put your mouse over the image the animation pauses..and returns to the normal :hover state.

I've tried a number of different things, including using this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/3R92G/2/, but to no avail...

Any help would be great.

```css
.person {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 62px 0 0 80px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.person-badge {
  width: 70px;
  height: 105px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.person-badge:before,
.person-badge:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #DDD;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEE 0%, #CCC 100%);
  transition: 500ms;
}

.person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #557ebb 0%, #55bbad 100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.person:nth-child(2) .person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #bb557b 0%, #6055bb 100%);
}

.person:nth-child(3) .person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #FC0 0%, #F88 100%);
}

.person:nth-child(4) .person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #cacc68 0%, #55bb95 100%);
}

.person:nth-child(5) .person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #6055bb 0%, #bb557b 100%);
}

.person:nth-child(6) .person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #FC0 0%, #8fbb55 100%);
}

.person:nth-child(7) .person-badge:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff9c47 0%, #e253b9 100%);
}

.person-badge:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.person-badge img {
  width: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.person-badge img.peculiar {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(80px)
}

.person-badge:hover img.normal {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(80px)
}

.person-badge:hover img.peculiar {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0)
}

.person h3 {
  margin: 0;
  Font-family: "rooney-web", serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

strong {
  color: #888;
  margin: px 0 5px 0;
  font-size: .8em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <div class="person-badge">
    <img class="normal" src="/images/person1-a.png">
    <img class="peculiar" src="/images/person1-b.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Person-1</h3><strong>maid of honor</strong>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="person-badge">
    <img class="normal" src="/images/person2-a.png">
    <img class="peculiar" src="/images/person2-b.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Person 2</h3>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="person-badge">
    <img class="normal" src="/images/person3-a.png">
    <img class="peculiar" src="/images/person3-b.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Person 3</h3>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="person-badge">
    <img class="normal" src="/images/person4-a.png">
    <img class="peculiar" src="/images/person4-b.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Person 4</h3>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="person-badge">
    <img class="normal" src="/images/person5-a.png">
    <img class="peculiar" src="/images/person5-b.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Person 5</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your css    `:hover` works, just let it be.
and for *javascript*:
    
    `element.classList.add('effect-class');
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.remove('normal-class');
    }, 1000);`

but you'll need to create classes to each effect in css!